# How to make volatile model/reference field?

Tags: mobx-state-tree

I want to add `selection` field in a model which should be array of references. If I add this to model `selection: types.array(types.reference(Todo))` then I have some undesirable side-effects like selection is being saved/loaded in snapshots and also changes to selection are recorded to the undo/redo history when using UndoManager middleware. If I put selection in volatile properties as just plain array then I lose reference sync capabilities(ie if one of selected elements removed from model selection will not be updated automatically).
Is there an approach which would allow to get benefits of both? Is there a way to ignore model field in patches/snapshots without moving it to volatile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good approach for models is to only have fields that belong to this entity and that you need in snapshots to send to server or elsewhere. Otherwise models become confusing and hard to manage.

Usually in such cases I put property like that into separate store or sub-store which bound to particular page/view for example. So this is structural issue more then anything else in my opinion.

Comment: What if this property is very actively being used in the actions of the model? How would I inject it from other store? Also it makes sense that selection is collection of references to the model objects, I just don't want it to be present in snapshots and recorded in undo/redo

Comment: Consider such options:

1. Pass this array as actions argument

2. Get it from parent store(s) or root store using `getParent` / `getRoot` functions

3. Store ids array in volatile state of the model and search for references manually using `resolveIdentifier` function when required.

Comment: Can you explain 2. Get it from parent store(s) or root store using getParent / getRoot functions ? I don't get how this helps. Currently I am considering having root store as regular mobx store, maintain selection as array of ids and use `resolveIdentifier` as you suggested and pass selection in the actions of MST tree model. The problem is that now I have to basically wrap every action in the MST tree model in the actions of root MobX store.

Comment: Your MST stores have structure of a tree which means you can navigate through it with help of those functions and get data in model/store from other store. So you can move references array out of model to some parent store and keep access to it.
I wouldn't recommend you to mix regular mobx stores and MST stores. You should be able to build your tree of store with MST just fine.

Comment: Ok I got it, I will try to move selection state up and apply undo/redo only one node I am interested in. I feel like I can accept this as an answer.